# Jetbrains extension in Dartium doesn't connect to Webstorm

Tags: dart, webstorm, dartium

I'm having problem with making the Jetbrains extension in Dartium connect to Webstorm.
In Chrome it works perfectly but not in Dartium.

I have checked the ports....

Anyone had the same experience?

Dartium:  31.0.1650.48

Jetbrains: extension: 2.0

Webstorm: 7.0.3

Comment: works fine for me (Dartium Version 31.0.1650.39, JetBrains IDE Support v2.0). What is written in extension console (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit, How do I know what's wrong?)

Comment: Ready to load system latest for WebStorm 7.0.3 (127.0.0.1:63343) logging.kt:43
System latest loaded for WebStorm 7.0.3 (127.0.0.1:63343) logging.kt:43
System latest connected to WebStorm 7.0.3 (127.0.0.1:63343)

Comment: Do you have Dart plugin installed? Did you choose Dartium as a target browser in JavaScript Debug run configuration? Where do you have Dartium installed ([Dart SDK home]/../chromium/chrome or some different location)?

Comment: Dart plugin installed. Dartium is installed in [Dart SDK home]/../dartium-mac-full-stable-31822.0/Chromium.app Chrome is set as target browser. And Dartium is set as Chrome path in Preferences/Web Browsers.

Comment: Replacing Chrome with Dartium in preferences won't work. You need to select Dartium explicitly in Run configuration to be able to debug

Comment: I can only select between FF and Chrome in the Run Configuration. I followed this guide. http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-dart.html "Preparing to run client-side Dart code in Dartium from WebStorm"

Comment: that's because you have Dartium installed to non-default location. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6695#comment=27-650454 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10427